# Can matshow display an image as imshow with PIL or another library?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I saw this post talking about `matshow` and `PIL` ([PIL/pillow image output is redder than the desired RGB values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27676326/pil-pillow-image-output-is-redder-than-the-desired-rgb-values)) but usually when we want to display an image we use `imshow` and `PIL`. I am asking if there is a way to do that with `matshow` and `PIL` only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matplotlib [`matshow`](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.matshow.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.matshow) is a wrapper for [`imshow`](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow), in that it *"sets origin to ‘upper’, ‘interpolation’ to ‘nearest’ and ‘aspect’ to equal."*

Therefore, anything that is possible with one of them is equally possible with the other.